# Second CASE statement causing query to fail?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've modified a query by adding a second CASE statement in Oracle, but the query is giving me an error.

The `CASE` statement I've added is below, and the full query is below that. I want to replace the word `'Athena'` with `'Platts Market Center'` and do nothing in the `ELSE` clause. Is that possible?

```sql
case
when software_vendor = 'Athena'
then software_vendor = 'Platts Market Center'
else software_vendor
end AS software_vendor,
```

```sql
select HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY,
       contract_no,
       shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city AS shipto_city,
       distributor,
       software_vendor,
       case
       when distributor = software_vendor
       then distributor
       else distributor ||': '|| software_vendor
       end AS Distributor_Combined,
       case
       when software_vendor = 'Athena'
       then software_vendor = 'Platts Market Center'
       else software_vendor
       end AS software_vendor,
       sum(new_annual) ACV
from   pp_finance_bank
where  contract_no in ('PL-M101409-X')
group by HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY,
       contract_no,
       shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city,
       distributor,
       software_vendor, 
       case
       when distributor = software_vendor
       then distributor
       else distributor ||': '|| software_vendor
       case
       when software_vendor = 'Athena'
       then software_vendor = 'Platts Market Center'
       else software_vendor
       end;
```

Comment: You are not using the case expression correctly. Please follow the correct syntax. And kindly provide the formatted query and sample data.

Comment: Hi, I've just modified the query. If you could let me know your thoughts on the amended query, they'd be appreciated. I get an error on the line where it states "software_vendor = 'Platts Market Center'" and the erorr says ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 144 Column: 17

Comment: Please do not edit the errors out of your question; doing that invalidates the answers. If you have supplementary questions then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or if you want your code reviewed then use [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two mistakes.

The first is your new case statement.  You have:

```
case when software_vendor = 'Athena' then software_vendor = 'Platts Market Center' 
else software_vendor end AS software_vendor,
```

But it should be:

```
case when software_vendor = 'Athena' then 'Platts Market Center' 
else software_vendor end AS software_vendor,
```

Also correct this same error in your group_by clause.  You have:

```
case when software_vendor = 'Athena' then software_vendor = 'Platts Market Center' 
else software_vendor
end;
```

But it should be:

```
case when software_vendor = 'Athena' then 'Platts Market Center' 
else software_vendor
end;
```

Also in the group by clause, you forgot the second "end".  You need an "end" for every case statement. You also forgot the comma after the first case statement in the group by clause:

You have:

```
group by HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY, contract_no, shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city, distributor, software_vendor,
case when distributor = software_vendor then
distributor else distributor ||': '|| software_vendor
```

But it should be:

```
group by HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY, contract_no, shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city, distributor, software_vendor,
case when distributor = software_vendor then
distributor else distributor ||': '|| software_vendor end,
```

Combining all of these corrections, here is the complete query, which should now work:

```
select HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY, contract_no, shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city AS shipto_city, distributor, software_vendor, 

case when distributor = software_vendor then distributor 
else distributor ||': '|| software_vendor end AS Distributor_Combined,

case when software_vendor = 'Athena' then 'Platts Market Center' 
else software_vendor end AS software_vendor,

sum(new_annual) ACV 

from pp_finance_bank 
where contract_no in ('PL-M101409-X') 

group by HOMOGENIZED_COMPANY, contract_no, shipto_addr1 || ', ' || shipto_city, distributor, software_vendor,

case when distributor = software_vendor then distributor 
else distributor ||': '|| software_vendor end,

case when software_vendor = 'Athena' then 'Platts Market Center' 
else software_vendor
end;
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you for spotting those errors and fixing them! The code actually runs without any errors now! So thank you! The only thing I've noticed is that it returns a column with "Software_Vendor_1" with the correct replacement ie Athena becomes 'Platts Market Center' But it doesn't replace it in the original column... I'm not sure why? If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help : ) .If this answer was satisfactory, please mark the answer as accepted.  For your second question regarding column names, please post another question, as you will need to post "expected output" and "actual output" details for that.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I've marked your answer as the answer.

Comment: No, you have not.  You need to click the checkmark on the left side, just below the number of votes.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have just seen this message. I thought that 'upvoting it' after which the 'upvote triangle' changes to orange actually marks it as the answer. But I've followed the instructions you gave and learnt something new! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use equality within the **WHEN**

It should be like this:

```
case when 
software_vendor = 'Athena' then 
 'Platts Market Center'
else software_vendor end as software_vendor
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work? Please see the updated code in the question. Any other ideas, please?

Comment: A missing keyword error on line 158, which is where the words 'CASE WHEN' start in the last CASE statement in the GROUP BY clause:     
case when 
software_vendor = 'Athena' then 
'Platts Market Center'
else software_vendor

end;

Comment: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: You are missing a comma between 1st case in group by and last case

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But I now get an error on this line: case when software_vendor = 'Athena' then 'Platts Market Center' else software_vendor Any other ideas?

Comment: You were missing an `END` after first CASE.